# Как снять активность с других элементов?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<img data-src="stol1_hover.png" class="img_table" src="stol1.png">
<img data-src="stol1_hover.png" class="img_table" src="stol1.png">

 $('img.img_table').click(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      var newSource = $this.data('src');
      $this.data('src', $this.attr('src'));
      $this.attr('src', newSource);
  });
```

Допустим кликнули на первую картинку, она выделилась, как сделать чтобы при клике на вторую, у первой пропадала активность,а вторая была активная.
В примере две картинки но может быть больше

Comment: что имеется ввиду под пропаданием активности?

Comment: @Grundy чтобы src обратно заменилось на stol1.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без сохранения дополнительной инфомации о статусе элемента - никак. Пометим активный элемент классом "active". Поменяем картинки для всех активных элеменов кроме щелкнутого (и уберем с них класс "active") перед тем, как обрабатывать элемент, на который щелкнули.

```
 $('img.img_table').click(function(){
   var $this = $(this);

   $('img.img_table.active').not($this).each(function() {
     var newSource = $(this).data('src');
     $(this).data('src', $(this).attr('src'));
     $(this).attr('src', newSource);
     $(this).removeClass("active");
   });

   var newSource = $this.data('src');
   $this.data('src', $this.attr('src'));
   $this.attr('src', newSource);
   $this.toggleClass("active");
});
```

Comment: `not` была функцией. Ну и не плохо было бы пояснения добавить

Comment: Спасибо, все отлично работает!